# Clearing a drawArea in haskell GTK

Tags: haskell, gtk, cairo, gtk2hs, drawingarea

I'm making a game using gtk/cairo in haskell, and I'm looking for a way to completely clear the drawing area (a widget of type drawingArea). When a widget resizes for instance, the drawing area is cleared automatically. I'm looking for a way to clear it manually.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't really need to clear anything ever. But perhaps you'll like [drawWindowInvalidateRect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.12.4/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Gdk-DrawWindow.html#v:drawWindowInvalidateRect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the DrawWindow of the DrawingArea using the function widgetGetDrawWindow, then call drawWindowClear with the DrawWindow as the argument.